# Function doesn't return value, only console.logs

Tags: javascript

I'm new in JS but now I'm totally confused. Why my function print logs into console but I can not return its value?

```
function searchObj (obj, query) {
    var variableToReturn="";
    for (var key in obj) {
        var value = obj[key];

        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            searchObj(value, query);
        }

        if (value === query) {
            console.log('property=' + key + ' name=' + obj["name"]);
            variableToReturn = obj["name"];
        }
    }
    return variableToReturn;
  }
```

but if I try that one in my code... it doesn't work at all

```
var newAttributes =searchObj(position, "1277,1795");
```

the variable is empty ;( I'm trying to understand it the whole day

I get right values only in my console:

```
property=backward name=brumi
```

This is one of the object which I'm looking for:

```
var position =  {
  current: {
    coordinates: '2408,1822',
    name: 'start',
    premiumPoints: 0,
    points: 0,
    right: Projects.detectProjectByKeyword("moneymat").coordinates,
    left: Projects.detectProjectByKeyword("wohnung").coordinates,
    forward: Projects.detectProjectByKeyword("supermarkt").coordinates,
    backward: "0,0"
  },
  start: //more objects to check
```

Comment: In your newAttributes variable, What is position, a variable or some kind of value?

Comment: You're missing a return on `return searchObj(value, query);`, (or `variableToReturn = searchObj(value, query);`)

Comment: James, I don't understand what do you mean? Lixus position is an object.

Comment: Inside searchObj (which returns a value), you call searchObj recursively and do nothing with the returned value.

Comment: I still don't know how to change my code ;(

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get a value that's nested deep inside an object, what does `query` contain that you are passing into the function?

Comment: it contains a coordination number. I updated my question. Could you please help me? This problem drives me crazy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141576/discussion-between-anna-k-and-james).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Modified the code as it seemed it was not working for more than two objects
  Here is working code:

```js
var position = {
  current: {
    coordinates: '2408,1822',
    name: 'start',
    premiumPoints: 0,
    points: 0,
    backward: "0,0"
  },
  some: {
    coordinates: '2409,1822',
    name: 'Some Start',
    premiumPoints: 0,
    points: 0,
    backward: "0,0"
  },
   more: {
    coordinates: '2400,1822',
    name: 'more Start',
    premiumPoints: 0,
    points: 0,
    backward: "0,0"
  }
};

function searchObj(obj, query) {
  var data ='';
  for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      if (typeof obj[property] === "object") {
       data = searchObj(obj[property], query);       
        if(data !='') return data; 
      }
      else {
        if (obj[property] === query) {         
          return  obj["name"];               
        }
      }
    }
  } 
  
  return data;
}

var data = searchObj(position, "2400,1822")
console.log("Result : " +data)
```

Since you are using recursive functions inside your code, you need to add "return" in front of them

In above code I have added `return` in for recursive `searchObj(value, query);` and `obj["name"];` .

let us know if this works

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding what you are trying to do is to recursively search a nested object and check that if there is a value in it that matches the parameter `query`. The problem with your code is that the variable `variableToReturn` gets initialised to '' each time the function is called. Since you are not returning `variableToReturn` when the value matches your query. The function will search through the nested objects until all the keys have been visited. The last key may not contain the value that you desire, and since you declare `variableToReturn` to "" at the beginning of your code, it will return that value Try running your code in chrome and you will see that you'll the function will return `""`. I believe that by adding a `return` to your recursive call and once you the current `value` matches the `query` will solve your issue. So your function should look something like below:

```js
function searchObj (obj, query) {
    // loop through the keys in obj
    for (let key in obj) {
        let value = obj[key];

        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            // current value is an object, so search recursively
            return searchObj(value, query);
        }

        if (value === query) {
            // found the value 
            return obj['name'];
        }
    }
    // can't find keys that match, so return empty string
    return '';
}
```

Comment: Explain exactly what you changed and why it was necessary. *"Try the code below"* isn't a description of the problem and solution.

Answer (score 0):

A return statement passes a value back to the immediate caller of the current function's call-frame. In the case of recursion, this immediate caller can be another invocation of that same function.

Hence need to return the result of the recursion, or else the method implicitly returns "undefined"

So,

```
var position =  {
  current: {
    coordinates: '2408,1822',
    name: 'start',
    premiumPoints: 0,
    points: 0,
    backward: "0,0"
  }
  };

  function searchObj (obj, query) {
    var variableToReturn="";
    for (var key in obj) {
        var value = obj[key];

        if (typeof value === 'object') {
          return  searchObj(value, query);
        }

        if (value === query) {

          variableToReturn = obj["name"];
        }
    }
    return variableToReturn;
  }

  var variableToReturn = searchObj(position, "2408,1822");
```